# How does a Melee Spell Attack work if you are already touching your target (not fighting edition)

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, advantage-and-disadvantage, non-combat

I recently asked this question about usage of a [melee attack spell when you are already touching the target](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107516/how-does-a-melee-spell-attack-work-if-you-are-already-touching-your-target). although it's pretty must answered, I had a non-fighting situation in mind and ended up with several fighting situations answers.

So here I reiterate my question for a non-fighting situation : Can we get some kind of leverage from already touching or being in proximity of an eventual target?

Take this situation: You are a caster and you are in a parlay with a foe. Discussion goes pretty well and you keep talking and moving around while arguing as peacefully as possible. You get to a point where both you and your foe are now close to each other. You put your hand on his shoulder (or shake his hand) and your foe confesses an abominable betrayal. At that moment, you decide this parlay was useless and prefer to see your foe suffer rather than become your ally.

Since you are already touching you target, can you get any kind of advantage from the fact that you are already making a contact that would allow you to inflict the spell's effect on the target?

Comment: This is a duplicate. Whether you are fighting or not fighting doesn't change the mechanics of attacks.

Comment: it is : it was my question, but I was suggested to make a new post about a non-fighting situation since the answers could differ

Comment: I was the one who made this suggestion. My point was it should be different question (not about spell attacks actually, but about unexpected attacks, *surprised* opponents, etc.). Not a link to the previous one with the note "now the same, but let's say I've touched him before combat begins".

Comment: my misunderstanding then

Comment: @Sirmyself imagine a unarmed attack (an unexpected punch) or a sneaky dagger attack (a backstab) instead of melee spell attack. Does this actually change the question?

Comment: It does, because when you do a weapon attack, the result of the attack is determined by the action of using a weapon, which imply the weapon being in movement. Casting a touch spells does not need momentum to have any effect, you just need to touch your target to unleash the magical energy.

Comment: I think it is not about comparison "fighting situation" with "non-fighting situation". It is all about what you want to achieve using the game rules. That's why I've asked for a specific example.

Comment: "Casting a touch spells does not need momentum to have any effect, you just need to touch your target" - why do you think so? The rules is silent about how exactly a spell attack looks. It is how *you* imagine a spell attack. If your DM imagines it different way, you should ask your DM first. Again, please describe a specific situation - just "a melee spell attack" is very generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same as a fighting situation. Once you initiate an attack, a fight is happening.

From the wording of your questions, you seem to be assuming the target won't react. This is not true. Once you begin casting a spell, even if its using stealthy metamagic, the target has a chance to react and move. The fact the caster is already touching the target is irrelevant. It is at most a social interaction that one can break from easily.

What you **can** achieve is to gain advantage, if you can distract the enemy or attack from hiding.

In a social situation, you might be able to win a dispute of Deception vs Insight to win advantage and/or surprise on your first attack.

But you still need to roll versus AC all the same.

Comment: The question was not about ignoring armor bonus like a touch-attack in previous editions. it was more about getting leverage of a situation you can achieve in a roleplay situation and you initiate the fight **by** the action of casting a touch spell.

Comment: @Sirmyself the roleplay situation you can leverage is the Deception vs Insight contest i mentioned above. The best you can achieve is to win advantage and/or surprise on your first attack.

Comment: I thought you were talking about the surprise mechanic, which does not give advanage. Although it gives some other benefits.